# Converting CSV file into PDF dynamically

Tags: csv

I have a simple CSV file that looks similar to:

```
pens, 23
bottles, 5
spoons, 6
chairs, 5
books, 12
```

I want to convert this into a PDF document. I have no clue on how could I do this. I have installed [mactex](https://www.tug.org/mactex/). It will be helpful, if you help me in getting started with this.

The problem that I am trying to solve is `pdf generation`. So the input will be a CSV file with around million entries and I want to generate a PDF document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You only want to put the contents of the CSV into a PDF as it is or do you want to apply some formatting to the data? Can you please clarify what is the output you want?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I want to put the contents of the CSV into a table. So a table could have 2 columns, first containing `pens`, `bottles` ,, and another containing corresponding numbers like `23 , 5 .. `

Comment: Have a look at the `csvsimple` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few more options using [`csvsimple`](https://ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple?lang=en).

You can use `\csvautotabular` to let `csvsimple` build a table for you:

```latex
\csvautotabular[
  table head={%
  \hline
    \bfseries Thing & \bfseries Amount \\
  \hline}]%
  {pens_and_bottles.csv}
```

> [image]

or, if you load the `booktabs` package then you can use `\csvautobooktabular` to get a prettier table:

```latex
\csvautobooktabular[
  table head={%
  \toprule
    \bfseries Thing & \bfseries Amount \\
  \midrule}]%
  {pens_and_bottles.csv}
```

> [image]

or you can build your own using `csvsimple`'s CSV processor:

```latex
\begin{tabular}{lc}
  \toprule
    \bfseries Thing & \bfseries Amount \\
  \midrule
    \csvreader[late after line=\\]{pens_and_bottles.csv}{}%
      {\csvcoli & \csvcolii}
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

> [image]

If you are using a rather large CSV file this will take more than one page, then you can load the `longtable` package then use `\csvautobooklongtable` (or build your own `longtable`, as in the previous example):

```latex
\csvautobooklongtable[
  table head={%
  \toprule
    \bfseries Thing & \bfseries Amount \\
  \midrule},
  table foot={\\\bottomrule}]%
  {pens_and_bottles.csv}
```

> [image]

Example with the four options:

```latex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{pens_and_bottles.csv}
pens, 23
bottles, 5
spoons, 6
chairs, 5
books, 12
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\csvautotabular[
  table head={%
  \hline
    \bfseries Thing & \bfseries Amount \\
  \hline}]%
  {pens_and_bottles.csv}

\bigskip

\csvautobooktabular[
  table head={%
  \toprule
    \bfseries Thing & \bfseries Amount \\
  \midrule}]%
  {pens_and_bottles.csv}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{lc}
  \toprule
    \bfseries Thing & \bfseries Amount \\
  \midrule
    \csvreader[late after line=\\]{pens_and_bottles.csv}{}%
      {\csvcoli & \csvcolii}
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\csvautobooklongtable[
  table head={%
  \toprule
    \bfseries Thing & \bfseries Amount \\
  \midrule},
  table foot={\\\bottomrule}]%
  {pens_and_bottles.csv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I created a PDF using `TeXShop`. Would you know any command line utility for this? I have installed `mactex` though but not sure if it comes with a terminal.

Comment: @Amanda `TeXShop` is just the editor. To run from the command line you can save the code as, say, `csv_to_pdf.tex` and then run `pdflatex csv_to_pdf.tex` from the command line.

Comment: Is there a way I could apply conditional colouring to the column values? Have asked a separate question though: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488364/colouring-column-values-based-on-a-specific-condition-how-could-i-do-this

Answer (score 1):

Here an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{caption}

% this code is only to create myfile.csv, you don't need it:
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{myfile.csv}
pens, 23
bottles, 5
spoons, 6
chairs, 5
books, 12
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]\centering
    \caption{A caption}
    \csvreader[
    tabular=lr,
    table head={\toprule
    My objects & My number\\
    \midrule},
    table foot=\bottomrule,
    no head,
    ]{myfile.csv}{}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you also add the steps to compile this? I was trying `TexLiveUtility` but was unable to understand how to generate the desired output from it.

Comment: @Amanda TeXLive Utility is a tool for updating your distribution. Typically people compile using a dedicated IDE like TeXworks, TeXShop, or `emacs`, `vim` etc. but everything can also be done from the command line if that's needed. [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/2693)

Comment: @Amanda There is no particular way to compile it, just run `pdflatex`. The way to do it depends on which editor you're using. Follow Alan's suggestion.

Comment: I tried this with a bigger csv and converted it to pdf using `TeXworks`. Complete data is not visible. Only one page has been generated. Is this something to do with the template?

Comment: @Amanda If the csv is very long, you should use `longtable`. See Phelype's answer.