# Colouring column values based on a specific condition. How could I do this?

Tags: color, longtable, conditionals

I am generating a big-table from a csv file using the latex code as given below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\csvautobooklongtable[
    table head={%
    \toprule
        \bfseries Name &\bfseries ID \\
    \midrule},
    table foot={\\\bottomrule}]%
    {sample-data.csv}

\end{document}
```

The generated document looks similar to:

[image]

Now, I want to make:

- IDs greater than 6 in bold and red. How could I do this?
- Also, for IDs less than 6, I want to append a symbol `<`. So 3 becomes `3 <`. How could I do this?

Here is link to the [CSV file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11qazsbHjKTD1IQpcORLNvNOxdj1_rL2dg8BusnwNwLo/edit?usp=sharing) that I am using to create a table.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). That is, can you post some csv data too.

Comment: @Andrew Have updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I struggled to get this to work using `\csvautobooklongtable` as it is fairly restrictive but I think (?) that using `\csvreader[longtable=ll,...`
creates a long table. Using this setup with [csvsimple](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple) you can create the table

[image]

using the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample-data.csv}
name, id
Daphne Kub, 1
Karolann Lebsack, 2
Charlotte Parisian, 3
Jairo Mayert, 4
Dr. Adrienne Schulist, 5
Elenora Pacocha, 6
Nikita Mraz, 7
Maya Tremblay, 8
Florine Konopelski, 9
Derrick Volkman, 10
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand\ColorID[1]{\ifnum#1>6\color{red}\textbf{#1}\else#1 $<$\fi}

\begin{document}

\csvreader[head to column names,longtable=ll,
           table head={\toprule\bfseries Name &\bfseries ID \\ \midrule},
           table foot={\\\bottomrule}
          ]{sample-data.csv}{}
          {\name &\ColorID\id}

\end{document}
```

The main point is that I head used `head to column names` to name the "variables" in each column and the macro `\ColorID` is used to make the big numbers bold red and to add `<` to the small numbers.

(I also added the csv file to the MWE using the [filecontents](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) package.)

**Edit** If you wan to keep your data file intact, and not add the `name, id` header, then you should remove the `head to column names` and then use, for example, `\csvcoli`  and `\csvcolii` in the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample-data.csv}
Daphne Kub, 1
Karolann Lebsack, 2
Charlotte Parisian, 3
Jairo Mayert, 4
Dr. Adrienne Schulist, 5
Elenora Pacocha, 6
Nikita Mraz, 7
Maya Tremblay, 8
Florine Konopelski, 9
Derrick Volkman, 10
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand\ColorID[1]{\ifnum#1>6\color{red}\textbf{#1}\else#1 $<$\fi}

\begin{document}

\csvreader[longtable=ll,
           table head={\toprule\bfseries Name &\bfseries ID \\ \midrule},
           table foot={\\\bottomrule}
          ]{sample-data.csv}{}
          {\csvcoli &\ColorID\csvcolii}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This gives an error saying `Undefined control sequence`. Snapshot: https://ibb.co/9yFFxgx

Comment: @Amanda Are you compiling my MWE or are you using your data? If you are using your data then you should add `name, id` to the top of your CSV file.

Comment: Using mine. Is there a way without it?

Comment: @Amanda Yes, wait a second and I'll edit.

Comment: Looks fine. Could you point me to the documentation of `csvreader`? I could not find the documentation under the ctan.org link you shared. I want to experiment by adding `hline` after each row. Would want to see some examples.

Comment: @Amanda `\csvreader` is part of the `csvsimple` package. I haven't used this package much but as far as I can see `\csvautobooklongtable` is a dumbed down version of ``csvreader`. (I just fixed the link in the post.)

Answer (score 3):

An approach with `readarray` and `listofitems`.

Here, I simply use the `\readdef` macro of `readarray` to input the file contents into a `\def\mytabledata`, while placing a `\\` at the end of each record of input.

Then, I develop the macro `\mytable` to build the `tabular` using a token list.  I perform a two-tier parsing of `\mytabledata` first separating rows by way of the inserted `\\`, and then looking for the comma in each row.  After the `\readlist*\IDlabel{}` invocation, `\IDlabel[3,1]` for example will contain the name associated with the 3rd file record, whereas `\IDlabel[4,2]` will contain the id-label associated with the fourth file record.  The macro `\IDlabel[]` is fully expandable, requiring two expansions to get to the tokens that were actually in the file data.  Thus, I have provided internal support macros like `\xxaddtotabtoks{}` to take its argument, expand it twice, and add it to the token list.

I set up a `\foreachitem` loop to go through each record and add tokens to the token list.  I have to create different logic for the first record, since that record is used to make the header.  For the other records, I output to the token list the data, while paying attention to the value of the id-label,  If it is less than 6, I add a `$<$` and if greater than 6, I make it bold red.

Once the loop is done, I merely need to output the token list inside a `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,xcolor,filecontents,readarray,booktabs}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample-data.csv}
Name, ID
Thing 1, 3
Thing 2, 5
Joe Smith, 6
Jane Doe, 11
\end{filecontents*}
\newtoks\tabtoks
\newcommand\addtotabtoks[1]{\tabtoks\expandafter{\the\tabtoks#1}}
\newcommand\xaddtotabtoks[1]{\expandafter\addtotabtoks\expandafter{#1}}
\newcommand\xxaddtotabtoks[1]{\expandafter\xaddtotabtoks\expandafter{#1}}
\newcommand\mytable[2][0]{%
  \setsepchar{\\/,}%
  \ignoreemptyitems%
  \tabtoks{}%
  \readlist*\IDlabel{#2}%
  \foreachitem\x\in\IDlabel[]{%
   \ifnum\xcnt=1\relax
     \addtotabtoks{\toprule\bfseries}
     \xxaddtotabtoks{\IDlabel[1,1] & \bfseries}
     \xxaddtotabtoks{\IDlabel[1,2] \\\midrule}%
   \else
     \xxaddtotabtoks{\IDlabel[\xcnt,1] & }%
     \ifnum\IDlabel[\xcnt,2]>6\relax\addtotabtoks{\bfseries\color{red}}\fi%
     \xxaddtotabtoks{\IDlabel[\xcnt,2]}%
     \ifnum\IDlabel[\xcnt,2]<6\relax\addtotabtoks{$<$}\fi%
     \addtotabtoks{\\}%
   \fi%
  }%
  \centerline{\begin{tabular}{ll}\the\tabtoks\end{tabular}}%
}
\begin{document}
\readarraysepchar{\\}
\readdef{sample-data.csv}\mytabledata
\mytable{\mytabledata}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It will be even more helpful if you could you also add some explanations and links that I could refer to.This all looks too complex to me.

Comment: Is there not a way to do with `csvautobooklongtable`?

Comment: @Amanda I have provided explanation.  I don't speak the language of `csvautobooklongtable`, whereas I am the author of `readarray` and coauthor of `listofitems`.  Thus, I speak these macros more fluently.